# Discord python bot error in regards to accepting a DM and DMing another user

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I'm trying to get the bot to get a message with specific content criteria. I then want the bot to message me with the user name/ID and the message that they left.

```
@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    if input.startswith('.direct'):
        content = re.sub(r'^\W*\w+\W*', '', message.content)
    elif message.content.startswith('!msg'):
        print (message.content)
        user = discord.utils.get(client.get_all_members(), id='505409899271028746')
    await client.send_message(message.author, "We appreciate your inquiry! As of right now, it doesn't match any questions that I have the ability to answer, so I've sent a message towards my creator to provide support.")
    await client.send_message(user, client.get_user_info(id) + content)
    await client.process_commands(message)
                               Edited version 10/29/2018 - 2:47 pm EST
```

I understand that the user could just DM me, but it's a step towards being able to automatically answer selected questions, and then forward the DM to me if it's unable to respond to them. But I've got a ways before I will be able to manage that.
http://prntscr.com/lbqy6y

Comment: Usually that error means that you have an `await` that is not inside a coroutine (an `async def` function). Is `user` you?  You could use `get_user_info` to get your `User` object instead.  What is `input`?  Also, that's not your `id`.  That looks like it might be your discriminator instead.

Comment: My discord is @Spectre#6223. Do I use other information for my ID? I'm not getting an error message now that I fixed the indention issue. But he's not DMing me when he's DM'd with the appropriate command.

Comment: `6223` is not your id.  You can get your id from developer mode of the discord client, or through your bot `(await client.application_info()).owner.id`

Comment: So it's my client ID? Also, the input is the one the user sends the bot. So the DM would be
!msg input
And then he would send me the user and the user's message